# How to turn off auto-update action of Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader, automatic-update

I'm feeling quite annoyed today since Adobe by someway automatically download an installer & ask me to run it - this explains me the slow internet connection in the last few days!

So, please if you know how to turn this off, share with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running Adobe Reader on Windows, go to the Edit menu, select Preferences, select "Updater" from the list and select the 3rd option: "Do not download or install updates automatically". I have Reader X, but it should be the same in older versions.

[image: Adobe Reader Updater]

Answer (score 1):

For those just finding this ?: A 2017 thread:
[Disable automatic updates in Adobe Reader DC?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1809982)

indicates the following:

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/PrefRef/Windows/Updater-Win.html

as one of two ways of disabling this - this method involving editing registry keys.  The other involves creating an Adobe account.  The "Updates" section is not present in Adobe Reader DC Preferences, currently.